# Update panel not working inside Gridview - Asp.Net/VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, updatepanel

When I click the image button 'imgPaymentMethod' I require the code to change the ImageUrl of the Image Button. However, nothing happens when clicked. I have also tried putting the entire gridview inside the update panel but then I get this error:

> A control with ID 'imgPaymentMethod' could not be found for the
>   trigger in UpdatePanel 'upPnlControls'

Front End..

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="fileID" DataSourceID="DSUploadedItems" CssClass="mGrid" 
                    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField visible="true" HeaderText="Price">
            <ItemTemplate>    
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBuyPrice" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Size="11px" Height="22px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBuyPrice_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("buyPrice")%>'>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0.00">Select:</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:LinkButton visible="false" ID="lnkPaymentMethod" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                    Text='<%# Bind("acceptPaypal")%>' > /></asp:LinkButton>
                <br /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblSoldStatus" visible="false" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text='<%# Bind("sold") %>' />
                <asp:Image ID="imgSoldStatus" alt="Sold Status" runat="server" width="100px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/iconSold.png" />
                <br />

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlControls" style="margin-top:0px;" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="imgPaymentMethod" eventname="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton visible="true" ID="imgPaymentMethod" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" width="50px" onclick="lnkPaymentMethod_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblDateBought" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text='<%# Bind("dateBought") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMarkAsSold" runat="server"  OnClick="markAsSold_Click" Text="Mark As Sold" Visible="true" ></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

VB Code..

```
Protected Sub lnkpaymentMethod_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim imgPaymentMethod As ImageButton = CType(sender, ImageButton)
    Dim currentRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(imgPaymentMethod.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)

    If imgPaymentMethod.ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/paypalIcon.gif" Then
        imgPaymentMethod.ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/cashIcon.gif"
    Else
        imgPaymentMethod.ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/paypalIcon.gif"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think typo issue `onclick="lnkPaymentMethod_Click"` should be  `onclick="lnkpaymentMethod_Click"`  since your method name is `lnkpaymentMethod_Click`

Comment: I've taken the IF statements out and simply just put imgPaymentMethod.ImageUrl="files/images/icons/testImage.png" but still nothing. @SelimYıldız  I've corrected the uppercase 'P' but no luck.

Comment: So the problem is that when you click the `imgPaymentMethod` button `lnkpaymentMethod_Click` method is not fired, right?

Comment: I've just tried putting some break point in and it looks like it faults on this line:         Dim currentRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(imgPaymentMethod.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)

Comment: Why do you need `currentRow` it seems you don't use it?

Comment: I guess do you want to get row of Gridview that you click, is that right?

Comment: Ah.. The actual code is massive so I cut it down. The GridViewRow is needed for something else which I've missed off. Looks like it's that causing the issue though. Yes I need it to get the row of Gridview that I click. It WAS working until I added the update panel to the front end so I believe i need to make a change to the Dim CurrentRow  line somehow.

Comment: Okay now it makes sense to me. I have added an answer please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion we had in comments, if I understood you correctly the problem here is this line:

```
Dim currentRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(imgPaymentMethod.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
```

If you want to get grid view row that you click via `imgPaymentMethod` button, you need to use [`NamingContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer) instead of `Parent` as follow:

```
Dim currentRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(imgPaymentMethod.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
```

Comment: Many thanks. That worked perfectly. Really appreciated Selim